# Bottom navigation is not working on react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator

Using the above blog ,i have created bottom navigation bar.Error says on line 29 "component" predefined property of Tab.Screen should be capital. 
[Error in App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTGWM.jpg)

This is my BottomNavigation.js file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import NotificationsNoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NotificationsNone';
import AddCircleOutlineTwoToneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircleOutlineTwoTone';
import HomeOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/HomeOutlined';
import WbIncandescentOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/WbIncandescentOutlined';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import AddDocument from '../screens/Notification';
import Notification from '../screens/AddDocument';
import AddProject from '../screens/AddProject';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      labeled="false"
      activeColor="black"
      labelStyle={{fontSize: 12}}
      //style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{tabBarIcon: () => <HomeOutlinedIcon />}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="AddDocument"
        component={AddDocument}
        options={{tabBarIcon: () => <AddCircleOutlineTwoToneIcon />}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="AddProject"
        component={AddProject}
        options={{tabBarIcon: () => <WbIncandescentOutlinedIcon />}}
        tabBarOptions={{showLabel: false}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notification"
        component={Notification}
        options={{tabBarIcon: () => <NotificationsNoneIcon />}}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default class BottomNavigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MyTabs />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

component is a property of Tab.screen but I am still getting error 
Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: your all component names are in capital , if yes .. the clear cache of npm.

Comment: I have cleared npm cache using following commands on windows 10 rm -r $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -r $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && 
rmdir -r node_modules/ 
&& npm cache clean --force &&
npm install && 
npm start -- --reset-cache still I am getting same error

Comment: The same code was running perfectly on expo but then I created new project on react-native and it's not working

Comment: I would suggest start from 0, just add hello world inside app , and check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was returning "NavigationContainer", Now I am simply returning Tab.Navigator to my App.js after that i am able to get bottom Navigator

My App.js looks like

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <BottomNavigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

i just removed NavigationContainer from BottomNavigation.But now my icon isn't getting displayed.
Modified BottomNavigation.js File

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import SimpleLineIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import AddDocument from '../screens/Notification';
import Notification from '../screens/AddDocument';
import AddProject from '../screens/AddProject';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function BottomNavigation(props) {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      // labeled="false"
      labelStyle={{fontSize: 12}}
      inactiveColor="white"
      activeColor="white"
      //style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="home-outline"
              color={color}
              size={26}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="AddDocument"
        component={AddDocument}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <AntDesign name="addfile" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="AddProject"
        component={AddProject}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <SimpleLineIcons name="magnifier-add" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
        tabBarOptions={{showLabel: false}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notification"
        component={Notification}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="bell-outline"
              color={color}
              size={26}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

My icons were not getting displayed so I referred to https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/463 just executed

> react-native link

and now my bottom Navigation Bar is working perfectly.